# Constants in Big O of two parameters with logarithm

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

$$O(\epsilon^{-2} * log(2/\delta)) = O(\epsilon^{-2} * log(1/\delta))
\,\,\,\,\,\;\;\; for \;0 < \delta < 1 \;and\; 0 < \epsilon < 0.5 $$

is this true? If we apply some logarithm laws to the first Big O we get:

$$O(\epsilon^{-2}*log(2) + \epsilon^{-2} * log(1/\delta))$$

where it would seem to me the equation only holds if $log(1/\delta) \ge log(2) $, but maybe some Big-O-magic makes it true for any $\delta$?

The reason I'm confused about this is, the way I understand Big O, e.g. $O(log(c/\delta))$ for some $c$ would be the same as $O(log(1/\delta))$ , but I don't know if this also holds with multiple parameters.

Comment: Presumably the $O$ notation here is meant to describe the behavior of these expressions as $\delta$ approaches $0$, in which case $\log(\frac1\delta)$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Yes that's correct, same for $\epsilon$. Thanks for pointing out